# How make full screen image landscape orientation in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am interesting in how to make full screen image landscape orientation, but without height: 100%, so width will be 100% but what is with height, because in react native height: not work=

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row',}}>
      <Image
        style={{
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: '100%',
        overflow: 'hidden',
     }}
     resizeMode='contain'
     source={{ uri: 'image path' }}
   />
```

Comment: But I dont want fixed height

Comment: give height is 100% in css

Comment: It will be full height on screen .. and I dont want that

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, install the package named @react-native-community/hooks ( npm i @react-native-community/hooks )
2. then import useDimentions and useDeviceOrientation from the package above.
   Example: import {useDimentions,useDeviceOrientation } from "@react-native-community/hooks"
   Destructure them like:
   const { landscape, portrait } = useDeviceOrientation();
   const { screen, window } = useDimensions();
   landscape, portrait are booleans
   screen, window are the objects with height, width and etc. ( just check it by console.log)
3. Then use screen.height or window.height to get the device's height